# Cleaning a bootable USB with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and I am trying to make an easy PS script that will clean a bootable USB when I run it. The problem is that when I run this code:

```
diskpart; select disk 1; clean; create partition memory;
```

It just stays stuck on diskpart. I have no idea how to go forward with this.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you out? If one did, consider checking out [what to do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Write a text file that contains the commands for `diskpart`:

```
select disk 1
clean
create partition memory
```

You can than supply the file using the `/s` switch for `diskpart`:

```
diskpart /s "C:\Temp\MyCommands.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to PowerShell. I hope you enjoy learning it.

PowerShell understands your one-line script as follows:

1. Resolve the meaning of `diskpart`
   Resolving... Found diskpart.exe
   Run it and wait for it to finish.
2. Resolve the meaning of `select`
   Resolving... It is an alias to `Select-Object` cmdlet.
   Run `Select-Object disk 1`.
   Return error: `Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '1'.`
3. Resolve the meaning of `clean`
   Resolving... No such alias, cmdlet or executable file found.
   Generate an error.
4. Resolve the meaning of `create`
   Resolving... No such alias, cmdlet or executable file found. 
   Generate an error.

Please understand that PowerShell is a programming language, not a classic CLI.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell has native cmdlets called [Format-Volume](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/storage/format-volume), [Initialize-Disk](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/storage/initialize-disk), and [New-Partition](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/storage/new-partition), which should do what you want.

Comment: The one gripe about the documentation is that it's not apparent in which version a cmdlet was introduced. Those cmdlets are no available on PowerShell 2.0 (Windows 7). The Tree on those docs would indicate it's available on Windows 10/Server 2016 so PowerShell 3.0.

Comment: @Seth, you are right. It's PowerShell 3.0. You can test by running PowerShell like this: `powershell.exe -version "3.0" -noprofile` , and see if it recognizes the cmdlet.